# Understanding attr_reader instance variable accessibility outside it's originating subclass

Tags: ruby

I am studying The Well Grounded Rubyist and I am having trouble understanding how to access the array stored in the instance var @cards of the subclass Deck.

```
class PlayingCard
  SUITS = %w{ clubs diamonds hearts spades }
  RANKS = %w{ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A }
  class Deck
    attr_reader :cards
    def initialize(n=1)
      @cards = []
      SUITS.cycle(n) do |s|
        RANKS.cycle(1) do |r|
          @cards << "#{r} of #{s}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

two_decks = PlayingCard::Deck.new(2)
puts two_decks
# => #<PlayingCard::Deck:0x007fb5c2961e80>
```

This makes sense, it returns the object id for two_decks from PlayingCard::Deck. Working to make this more useful, the only way I could come up with to access the array stored in @cards was to add another method  Deck#show. Now I can make call other methods on @cards, like I had set out to do. The simple example allows to get the count of @cards:

```
class PlayingCard
  SUITS = %w{ clubs diamonds hearts spades }
  RANKS = %w{ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A }
  class Deck
    attr_reader :cards
    def initialize(n=1)
      @cards = []
      SUITS.cycle(n) do |s|
        RANKS.cycle(1) do |r|
          @cards << "#{r} of #{s}"
        end
      end
    end
    def show
      @cards
    end
  end
end

two_decks = PlayingCard::Deck.new(2).show
p two_decks.count
# => 104
```

I am confused as I thought that the attr_reader was allowing the @cards instance var to be seen outside the class. Does the Cards#show method increase the scope of the variable? Is there a better way that I am missing? Am I off as to where manipulation/ info gathering from @cards should occur? Thanks!

Comment: `@cards` is an instance variable and what `attr_reader` does is allowing you to access (read the value of) this instance variable, which you have successfully done in `show` method.

Comment: Are you still confused? Did you understand Andrey's comment?

Comment: I do thanks. At first I thought that it would be available outside of the PlayingCard class.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate way for me to get access to the array represented by @cards? Other than creating/calling the show method on the PlayingCard::Deck.new instance?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you generally cannot change a variable's scope to see it outside of its class. The proper way to expose a variable is to wrap it in a method like you did with

```
def show
  @cards
end
```

The `attr_reader` method is a convenience method which automatically creates the method for you. So adding `attr_reader :cards` implicitly adds this method to your class:

```
def cards
  @cards
end
```

Which means you can now access @cards using `two_decks.cards` and you don't need the `show` method at all.

It might be worth mentioning that you can also use `attr_writer :cards` to add this method:

```
def cards= value
  @cards = value
end
```

Which can be called like so: `two_cards.cards = some_value`

And you can use `attr_accessor :cards` to automatically add both the read and the write methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was going for. I think my confusion was not realizing the attr_* property could be called like a method. Thanks for the help!

```js
class PlayingCard
  SUITS = %w{ clubs diamonds hearts spades }
  RANKS = %w{ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A }
  class Deck
    attr_reader :cards
    def initialize(n=1)
      @cards = []
      SUITS.cycle(n) do |s|
        RANKS.cycle(1) do |r|
          @cards << "#{r} of #{s}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

two_decks = PlayingCard::Deck.new(2)
p two_decks.cards.count
```